# Is it useful to use override and final keywords with a same member function?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Is it ever useful to declare a member function as both override and final? Why or why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`override` ensures that the function is virtual and is overriding a superclass definition (otherwise, a compile-time error is generated), while `final` means that subclasses cannot override it further. So yes, it makes perfect sense when you are overriding a superclass function and you do not want subclasses to override it again.

For instance, consider the following hierarchy:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {}
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void foo() override final {} // <-- Overrides A::foo
};

class C: public B {
public:
    //void foo() override {} <-- Error here!
};
```

Comment: This does not really show a use case. Why would you make the method virtual in the first place, if you are making it final?

Comment: @sp2danny Are you referring to Stefano or to my comment? I provided (the basis for) an example in a comment to your (now deleted) answer.

Comment: I'm referring to the following train of thought: If it was previously introduced, isn't `final` and `override final` the same thing? And if it's just introduced, why is it `virtual` to begin with?

Comment: @sp2danny: No, [they're _not_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/802078b790db2a29) [the same thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33a1b53f6e07b7c6).

Comment: This thing now makes sense. Think it should be in the answer.